# How can I instantiate my BottomNavBar with the current index?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation

I have a Flutter app with multiple pages (Home, Meditation, Profile), divided into classes.
I have a drawer class which contains my BottomNavigationBar.

The problem is the following:
When I launch my application and I click on a button of my BottomNavigationBar, I change pages but the active icon in the bar remains "Home". It's only when I return that the icon updates.

I understand that the problem comes from my drawer class which instance _selectedIndex with the index of the "home" page. Is it possible to pass my drawer the current index instead of that of a specific page?

Here is the code of my home page :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:harmony/myAppbar.dart';
import 'drawer.dart';

class home extends StatelessWidget {
  final int indexPage = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(),
      themeMode: ThemeMode.system,
      home: const Scaffold(
        appBar: myAppBar(),
        bottomNavigationBar: drawer(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

my meditation page :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'myAppbar.dart';
import 'drawer.dart';

class meditation extends StatelessWidget {
  final int indexPage = 1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(),
      themeMode: ThemeMode.system,
      home: const Scaffold(
          appBar: myAppBar(),
          body: Center(
            child: Text('Meditation Page'),
          ),
          bottomNavigationBar: drawer()),
    );
  }
}
```

my drawer :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'home.dart';
import 'meditation.dart';
import 'music.dart';
import 'profile.dart';

class drawer extends StatefulWidget {
  const drawer({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<drawer> createState() => _drawerPageState();
}

class _drawerPageState extends State<drawer> {
  final List<Widget> _pages = [
    home(),
    meditation(),
    music(),
    profile(),
  ];

  int _selectedIndex = home().indexPage;

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
      Navigator.push(context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => _pages[_selectedIndex]));
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BottomNavigationBar(
      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
      currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
      items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.home),
          label: 'Home',
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.self_improvement),
          label: 'Meditation',
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.music_note),
          label: 'Music',
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.person),
          label: 'Profile',
        ),
      ],
      selectedItemColor: Colors.blue,
      unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
      onTap: _onItemTapped,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the current index as a parameter of your bottom bar:

```
...
class drawer extends StatefulWidget {
  final int index;

  const drawer({Key? key, required this.index}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<drawer> createState() => _drawerPageState();
}

class _drawerPageState extends State<drawer> {
  final List<Widget> _pages = [
    home(),
    meditation(),
    music(),
    profile(),
  ];

  int _selectedIndex = home().indexPage;

  @override
  initState() {
      super.initState();
      _selectedIndex = widget.index;      
  }
  ...
```

and when calling your widget

```
bottomNavigationBar: drawer(index: indexPage)),
```

Comment: Thank you ! I'll try but it seems like it's exactly what I want !